# ng-tags-input with dynamic model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-tags-input

how can i use ng-tags-input inside a ng-repeat loop, when each element has different tags? How can i set the ng-model dynamically?

```
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="file in files">
                {{file}} <tags-input ng-model="tags"></tags-input>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.tags =  ['tagA','tagB'];

        // $scope.tags['file1'] =  ['tagA','tagB'];
        // $scope.tags['file2'] =  ['tagC','tagD'];
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do the `tags` relate to `files`?  you need a `tags` array for each iteration of `ng-repeat`. can you do `file.tags`?

Comment: What about the `tags` array? Are these static or you want to store values from run time ?

Comment: @Claies Thanks a lot! Yes, file.tags works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same solution as Claies suggested but I tried my self.
Please check working example : http://plnkr.co/edit/bNQ6DrUlNWdEAi8fnvBr?p=preview

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="file in files">
      {{file.name}}
      <tags-input ng-model="file.tags"></tags-input>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.files = [
    {
      name : 'file1','tags': [{text: 'tagA'},{text: 'tagB'}]  
    },
    {
      name : 'file2','tags': [{text: 'tagC'},{text: 'tagD'}]  
    }  
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ng-model` to form a more complex expression such as `tags[file]`, assuming `file` is the string corresponding to the key in your dictionary.

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
     <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="file in files">
             {{file}} <tags-input ng-model="tags[file]"></tags-input>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$scope.tags = {
  'first': [{text: 'Tag1'}, {text: 'Tag2'}],
  'second': [{text: 'Tag3'}, {text: 'Tag4'}]
};
$scope.files = ['first', 'second'];
```

[See plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wKf9G3YgECuMIA9Gq1Uq?p=preview)